# Nuxtjs ScrollSpy through Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-pond-ehixi?file=/pages/index.vue

Hi, let me explain the design first before the problem so we all are on the same view

I am currently new to Vue and working on a Nuxtjs project with the Vuex store.
In my `layout/default.vue`, I have a `Header`, `Footer` component, and `<Nuxt />` between them.
Both `Header` & `Footer` will be fixed/sticky in the top and bottom.
The main content will be scrollable and it has cards inside it.

⚙️ Problem:

The `Header` component will have navigation which will get *highlighted* when the correct card is in the viewport (at least 100px offset).
In the `Footer` component, there are buttons to navigate the user to previous or next card (100px offset included) depending on what card the user is looking at.

I am using [vue2-scrollspy](https://github.com/cavanmflynn/vuex-scrollspy) but it's not working (see codesandbox). I am also not sure if this is the right module to do the job.

**⚠️ UPDATE 01**

Scroll Spy is working now when the user scrolls the page & I added a watcher to update the store values. The remaining issue is to scroll the user to the previous or next card depending on what they are viewing. On `vue2-scrollspy` document, it says the following.

```
$scrollTo(index: int) is provided on scope Vue instance to invoke a scroll to the given section index.
```

However, calling `$scrollTo(0)` or `this.$scrollTo(0)` giving me an error:

```
this.$scrollTo is not a function
```

Codesandbox has been updated with the latest changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this is how I fix my issue

On the `/pages/index.vue` I added *ID* on every card and a watcher to check every time scroll spy change `count` value. If `count` change, I update the value on the store.global [currentView, previousView, nextView].

**/pages/index.vue**

```
<template>
  <main class="main" v-scroll-spy="{ data: 'count', offset: 250 }">
    <div
      :key="item"
      v-for="(item, index) in sections"
      :id="`view-${index}`"
      class="main-child card"
      :class="[`bg-${index}`]"
    >
      <h1>{{ item }}</h1>
      <p>{{ `${index} ${item} ${count}` }}</p>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    };
  },
  computed: {
    sections() {
      return this.$store.state.sections;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    count(newValue) {
      this.$store.dispatch("updateCurrentView", newValue);
      this.$store.dispatch(
        "updatePreviousView",
        newValue === 0 ? 0 : newValue - 1
      );
      this.$store.dispatch(
        "updateNextView",
        newValue === this.sections.length - 1
          ? this.sections.length - 1
          : newValue + 1
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**/store/index.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
  global: {
    currentView: 0,
    previousView: 0,
    nextView: 1
  },
  sections: ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"]
});

export const mutations = {
  UPDATE_CURRENT_VIEW(state, value) {
    state.global.currentView = value;
  },
  UPDATE_PREVIOUS_VIEW(state, value) {
    state.global.previousView = value;
  },
  UPDATE_NEXT_VIEW(state, value) {
    state.global.nextView = value;
  }
};

export const actions = {
  updateCurrentView({ commit }, value) {
    commit("UPDATE_CURRENT_VIEW", value);
  },
  updatePreviousView({ commit }, value) {
    commit("UPDATE_PREVIOUS_VIEW", value);
  },
  updateNextView({ commit }, value) {
    commit("UPDATE_NEXT_VIEW", value);
  }
};
```

On the component where the button `up` & `down` is located, I can then call the global state and add actions to scroll to previous or next element base on the global values:

**/components/WithUpDownButtons.vue**

```
export default {
  computed: {
    global() {
      return this.$store.state.global
    }
    ...
  },
  methods: {
    scrollTopPrevious() {
      // scroll to previous element into view
      // this.$scrollTo(this.previousView) < not working
      document
        .getElementById(`view-${this.global.previousView}`)
        .scrollIntoView(true);
    },
    scrollTopNext() {
      // scroll to next element into view
      // this.$scrollTo(this.nextView) < not working
      document
        .getElementById(`view-${this.global.nextView}`)
        .scrollIntoView(true);
    }
  }
};
```

If we need to add scroll animation, we can update the `scrollIntoView(true)` with the following:

**/components/WithUpDownButtons.vue**

```
...
  methods: {
    scrollTopPrevious() {
      // scroll to previous element into view
      document
        .getElementById(`view-${this.global.previousView}`)
        .scrollIntoView({
          top: 0,
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    },
    scrollTopNext() {
      // scroll to next element into view
      document
        .getElementById(`view-${this.global.nextView}`)
        .scrollIntoView({
          top: 0,
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    }
  }
...
```